# How do I transfer all child elements to a group div wrappers recursively in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

For the code below I want each `et_pb_module` to transfer to div with class of `item` recursively.

```
<div class="et_pb_column">

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 1
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 2
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 3
    </div>

</div>


<div class="owl-wrapper">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The correct output looks like this:

```
<div class="owl-wrapper">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">

            <div class="et_pb_module">
                content 1
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">

            <div class="et_pb_module">
                content 2
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">

            <div class="et_pb_module">
                content 3
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My current jquery code looks like this:

```
  $(".et_pb_column > .et_pb_module").each(function() {
    $("#owl-demo .owl-item > .item").append($(this).html());
  });
```

The problem with my jquery code is that it copes all `et_pb_module` to each div with class of `item`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: #owl-demo is not in your HTML.  I assume it wraps the owl-wrapper?

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves Sorry. I forgot to type. It's suppose to be the wrapper of `owl-wrapper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking to do:

```
$(".et_pb_column > .et_pb_module").each(function(i) {
    $(".owl-item > .item")[i].append($(this)[0]);
});
```

Here is the working code:

```js
 $(".et_pb_column > .et_pb_module").each(function(i) {
    $(".owl-item > .item")[i].append($(this)[0]);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_column">

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 1
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 2
    </div>

    <div class="et_pb_module">
        content 3
    </div>

</div>


<div class="owl-wrapper">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Inspect to see the set is correct.